# Why is 'CPU usage' unavailable in diagnostic tools?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. When I use diagnostic tools, 'cpu usage' is always greyed out. Why?

[image]

Comment: `CPU Sampling` is `CPU usage` and this is already included when you select the Performance Wizard.

Answer (score 12):

If Performance Wizard is enabled other tools will be disabled because Performance Wizard uses a different collection approach. Please uncheck "Performance Wizard" to enable "CPU Usage". After you collected data using "CPU Usage" tool you can invoke "Create detailed report..." and you will get exactly the data provided by Performance Wizard in CPU Sampling mode.